# Firebase authentication users

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use the users from MySQL in my PHP application for chatting with each other and using firebase as a datastore. For example, there is a table of the user in PHP myadmin my website is also in PHP and my firebase module is in javascript.

I want to implement a functionality of chatting with real-time response time

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a NodeJS application top run in the background of your server that reads the MySQL DB and writes to Firebase. The NodeJS Firebase module is very easy to use, so adding to a Realtime DB will be easy.

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: No one here has time to create your project for you. Please at least look into what I mentioned.